# Are there any methods to quantify complexity of finite problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

On page 348 of "*Sipser M. Introduction to the Theory of Computation. Cengage Learning; 2012 Jun 27*", it says

> Perhaps at some time in the future, methods that can quantify the complexity of finite problems will be developed. But current methods are asymptotic and hence apply only to the rate of growth of the complexity as the problem size increases --- not to any fixed size.

My question is, "are such methods developed currently?"

Comment: There haven't been any developments since 2012 as far as I know. However, methods do exist – circuit complexity, Kolmogorov complexity, and so on. That was also true back then.